# How to populate a vector<vector <Foo*> >?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector

I have a class RWLock, and I'm trying to create a `vector<vector<RWLock*>>`, a two dimensional vector of pointers to RWLock.
What I'm doing is:

```
vector<vector <RWLock*>> board = vector<vector <RWLock*>>(height);
RWLock* lock;
for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; ++i)
{
    board[i] = vector <RWLock*>(width, NULL);
    for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; ++j)
    {
        lock = (RWLock*) malloc(sizeof(RWLock*));
        *lock = RWLock();
        board[i][j] = lock;
    }
}
```

When I run this, however, I get

```
*** glibc detected*** ./test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x[some hexa] ***
```

I've debugged this enough to know that this pops up as soon as I call "board[i] = vector (width, NULL);" the second time, with i being equal to 1. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I had to copy the code by hand and the inner loop (because I'm writting the actual code in a VM without an internet connection) was wrong. The code here now matches the actual code.

Comment: why not `board[i][j] = new RWLock();` ?

Comment: Do you have `j` defined elsewhere? Your inner loop should use `j` instead of `i`.

Comment: Second loop should also be over width, not height.
Where is j declared anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Topi Ojala's concern about your vairable *i* being re-used, and *j* not being declared, you have an issue here:

```
    lock = (RWLock*) malloc(sizeof(RWLock*));
    *lock = RWLock();
    board[i][j] = lock;
```

you are allocating the space for a RWLock, but never constructing an RWLock.

You are then on the second line constructing a temporary `RwLock()`, and invoking the assignment operator of the first RWLock, which isn't really an RWLock because as mentioned above, it hasn't been constructed yet. Invoking the assignment operator like this will result in undefined behaviour.

just use new instead:

```
   lock = new RWLock;
   board[i][j] = lock;
```

or, if you really really want to allocate with malloc, use placement new

Comment: Thanks, I'm very rusty with the OOP part of C++. That seems to have solved my problem.
The i and j thing was just a dumb mistake I made because I had to copy the code by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same for-loop variable *i* in your loops. Change the inner-loop variable to *j* and it should work. :)